# Centered image when DIV using justify

Tags: css

How to make image centered like this when all texts in DIV using Justify?

-------------------
texttexttexttext
texttexttexttext
     [image]
texttexttexttext
texttexttexttext
--------------------

```
<div style="text-align:justify;">
    texttex text te txtetext texttex text te txtetexttexttex text te txtetext texttex text te txtetext texttex text te txtetext  texttex text te txtetexttexttex text te txtetext texttex text te txtetext <img src="image.jpg"> texttex text te txtetexttexttex texttex text te txtetexttexttex.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as below.

```
img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XPNQA/)**

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you

```
 <div style="text-align:center;">
   <p style="text-align:justify;">texttex text te txtetext texttex text te
   txtetexttexttex text te txtetext texttex text te       txtetext texttex text 
   te txtetext    texttex text te txtetexttexttex text te txtetext texttex
   te    txtetext</p>

 <img src="image.jpg">

   <p style="text-align:justify;" >texttex text te txtetexttexttex texttex
   text te txtetexttexttex.</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Use the p tag instead of the span to get the desired effect
http://jsfiddle.net/c5PLx/

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML to:

```
<div id="image-div" style="text-align:justify;">
    text...<img src="image.jpg"/> text...
</div>
```

then in your CSS add something like:

```
#image-div img{   
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TdLv7/5/)

Or use paragraph tags (`<p>`) and have your HTML as:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <p style="text-align:justify;">texttex text te txtetext texttex text te txtetexttexttex text te txtetext texttex text te txtetext texttex text te txtetext texttex text te txtetexttexttex text te txtetext texttex text te txtetext</p>
    <img src="image.jpg" />
    <p style="text-align:justify;">texttex text te txtetexttexttex texttex text te txtetexttexttex.</p>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TdLv7/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EPQ9Z/2/)?

**HTML**

```
<div class "text_img">texttex text te txtetext texttex text te txtetexttexttex text te txtetext texttex text te txtetext texttex text te txtetext texttex text te txtetexttexttex text te txtetext texttex text te txtetext
    <img src="http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/sites/default/files/2012/12/img_logo_blue.jpg">texttex text te txtetexttexttex texttex text te txtetexttexttex.</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.text_img {
    text-align: justify;
}
.text_img img {
    margin 0px auto;
    display: block;
}
```